Calculating how many characters are too many in a vbox
In this example, I have three vtop boxes, each defined as \vtop to 60pt. The first box is ok, as you may see by the vrules, the second and third are to long. How may I calculate and display the number of characters I must delete, to keep the right length (60pt) of the \vtop ?
For this example, an underfull box may say: Characters left (31-40), an overfull box may say: Too many characters (41-80) or Too many characters (41-98).
PS: I do not want to adjust the maximum length of the boxes by using \vtop spread 60pt
   \TeX

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. 

\vskip\baselineskip
\parindent=0pt
\hbox{\vrule\hskip4pt\vtop to 60pt{\hsize=100pt 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 }
\hskip4pt\vrule\hskip4pt\vrule\hskip4pt
\vtop to 60pt{\hsize=100pt 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 4142 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 }
\hskip4pt\vrule\hskip4pt\vrule\hskip4pt
\vtop to 60pt{\hsize=100pt 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90  91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 }
\vrule}
\vfill
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. 
\bye


I don't see it is possible to answer this as there is no particular number of characters you can/must delete to make the content fit. different characters have different dimensions. moreover, you don't say whether you mean input or output characters. is t\^y 2, 3 or 4 characters? if you use a monowidth font, no punctuation and confine yourself to letters and digits in ascii, you still have the question of spaces. these are not characters in the output at all, but clearly affect the overall dimensions. if this is just an exercise, you could narrow it down. otherwise, please tell us the goal.

TeX doesn't consider any of them 'OK': the first is just underfull rather than overfull. the first is, essentially, infinitely bad as far as tex is concerned. of course, deleting characters would only make the box even worse in this case.

@cfr I do not understand your comment. Every character in TeX must have dimensions, even the glue and the spaces. Every word and every line is a box of boxes, shrinked or stretched by glue. Therefore all of them must be calculable, otherwise TeX wouldn't work. I think, the characters are the easiest way to manipulate the filling of the boxes, finer adjustments may follow.  I will appreciate every improvement.

@cfr Surely, one should not fiddle around with glue or badness?

There are cases where adding additional characters might make a paragraph have fewer lines, or where removing characters will make it longer, so this isn't really possible in general. But if your text is just pairs of numbers in Computer Modern, all of its digits are 0.5em wide and its space's natural width is 0.33em, so with a 10pt font size, there are approximately 0.225 characters per point.

Suppose you know that three characters have widths of x, y and z. So their total width is x + y + z. But the result of typesetting the three characters as a word may be less than, more than or equal to x + y + z. Think about e.g. VAT or Waffling. How many characters are there in affine? 7? That's the number you type. 4? That's the number of glyphs 8? That's the number of characters, 4 of which disappear in processing.

Your question refers to "characters" which has no general answer, but your example only has digits these are all the same width and have no inter-letter kerns or ligatures (which is also typically true of CJK text) so for such text that does have a numeric answer that you can calculate, but is that your question?

@David Carlisle See my answer below. I think, the dimensions can not be calculated in general, one has to fill in a personally typical text, to catch the individuality.

With the text as in your question with repeated pairs of digits the needed number can be calculated exactly. For general text what users a value from some typical text? Why not measure in each case? I do not think the question is clear enough to answer

First, I tried to find out the optimal width of the \vboxes using an example text. Then, I added a number of letters, to see, when the box is overfilled and how many letters and spaces I might add or must delete. Change the content of \def\optionalchar{m }%optional and the number of iterations in \addchars{40} to see the effect.
Change the values in
\horizontalsize=130pt %start optional
\loop \ifdim\horizontalsize<140pt %end optional

to define the range of possible widths of the vboxes.
  \TeX
    %\raggedright
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \parindent=0pt
    \newbox\unitbox
    \newdimen\horizontalsize
    \horizontalsize=0pt
    \newdimen\verticalsize
    \verticalsize=0pt
    \newdimen\horizontalsizestep
    \newcount\charnum
    \charnum=0
    \newcount\add
    \add=0
    \def\optionalchar{m }%optional
    \def\addchars#1{\loop \ifnum\add<#1\global\advance\charnum by 1 \optionalchar \advance\add by 1 \repeat} %adding chars to see how many are to many
    %begin
    \verticalsize=40pt %optional
    \horizontalsize=130pt %start optional
    \loop \ifdim\horizontalsize<140pt %end optional
    \setbox\unitbox=\vbox to \verticalsize{\hsize=\horizontalsize The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \charnum=44 \addchars{40}} %vary the number of addchars
    Width: \the\wd\unitbox\ x Height: \the\ht\unitbox\ x Depth: \the\dp\unitbox\vskip\baselineskip
    \horizontalsizestep=\the\wd\unitbox\divide\horizontalsizestep by \charnum 
    \hbox{\vrule\hskip2pt\box\unitbox \hskip2pt\vrule}\vskip2\baselineskip
    Width increased by: \the\horizontalsizestep\ Chars: \the\charnum 
    \advance\horizontalsize by \horizontalsizestep
    \repeat
    \bye

